# moving to Germany to stay closer to my children

Tags: family, children, divorce

I am recently divorced and our children are staying with my ex-wife for the next 2 years. She moved to Berlin (studying) and that is where my children are now as well. We are all US citizens.

I'm moving to Berlin, too, so I can stay close to my children. I don't have a salaried work right now (a co-founder in a start-up in US) but I do have sufficient funds in my banking accounts. I do plan to study at a University in Berlin, but this is not for this year (need to learn the language first).

What type of visa would be best for my situation?

Comment: I need to do some research before posting a proper answer, but i don't think it looks good.  You may be able to motivate something based on family ties, but I'm skeptical.  Better to enroll in a course of study in English if you can find one, or get a job, or open a German office of your company.

Comment: I'm eagerly waiting for your response, thanks for looking into it

Comment: @phoog would OP be allowed to remotely work for their startup on a study visa? If I recall correctly on Travel SE there are cases where US citizens attracted a UK ban in a similar fashion.

Comment: @mts I don't think a student would be allowed to work remotely with a student visa, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to apply for a `family reunion` visa only to make an officer extremely puzzled over my situation. She needed to consult (at length!) with her colleagues and her supervisor to get back to me and say: "this visa is only for family members that stay with *adult* family members". So if my children were 18+ - only then could I have used that option.

So (scrambling for time) I went to the Foreigners' Registration Office at 2am (it is summer so crowds of students are applying) and ended up applying for a `studying the language` visa for 1 year. This type of visa is extremely flexible and I can change it to either `studying at University`, or `working`, or any other type at any time with no penalties.